# The plural form of the word blue

Tags: meaning

“The blue” is sometimes used in literary speech or writing to mean “the sky” or “the sea”. Does its plural form indicate both the sky and sea?

For example, is it a meaningful sentence if I say “the horizon is where the blues intersect”?

Comment: You can have more than one blue, so it's fine to say the horizon is where their blues intersect. Nevertheless, *blues* plural [also means something entirely different](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mmWB6KsM8AA) so be careful when you use it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and have never heard the sky or the sea referred to as "the blue". Is this usage peculiar to a specific dialect?

Comment: @RMac: You've never heard the [USAF hymn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JP3whmQ_OZc)?

Comment: @RMac - Wow, that came from out of the blue!

Comment: In normal conversation, it would sound a little odd, but you're talking about literary language, so I'd say go ahead and use it, but just in this specific case.

Comment: @RMac do you see the light blue above you and the deep blue in front of you?  The horizon is where the blues intersect.

Comment: In the nuclear strategy literature, BOOB was used as an acronym for “bolt out of the blue”. So “out of the blue” must have been well enough known for writers to use it in this indirect way.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.

Comment: 'The blue' is a fixed phrase in English, usually met in 'into the blue'. It is a non-count usage, and no plural form is used. This is not to say that 'the blues' is not used in other fixed phrases, these having no singular form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth For once you and I agree. Robusto maintains "you can have more than one blue". That very much depends on the sense in which "blue" is being used. The OP's idea that "the blue" can refer either to the sky or the sea -separately- is an entirely new one on me.

Comment: @WS2 'Into the blue' shows a non-count usage without a plural form (by definition, it doesn't pluralise, but that's a different matter). 'He often plays the blues' shows a non-count usage with no singular form. // Count usages include 'Three blues were injured in the match' and 'The two blues Mondrian uses here are profoundly different'.

Comment: I think it would be much more comprehensible if you said *where the blue meets the blue* (although even that's a little obscure).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing's wrong with it. It even has a kind of literary value. Making it clearer is always advisable when your listeners don't get it, but if they do, then just go ahead. It sounds a bit off just because it is not used as frequently as it is in literature, not because it is inappropriate. It is not lexically incorrect, neither is it grammatically flawed.

Answer (score 1):

“Blue” or “the “blue” can take a normal plural when used as the name of a colour, e.g.

“The blues and greens in the painting are especially evocative.”

It has various **figurative** usages such those mentioned (much rarer alone in English than in languages such as French) where *the plural is never used*.

It is more common in an **idiomatic** sense meaning “nowhere” — esp. “Out of the blue” (perhaps an allusion to the sky”) but again is never used in the plural.

One obvious reason why “the blues” might sound strange is that it is an idiomatic expression for “depression”. However the figurative use of “the blue” to mean “the sea” refers to it in a general sense (as opposed to the land) rather than to a specific sea, such as the Mediterranean. Hence there is no plural.

Using it to mean both the sky and the sea in one sentence is not English usage and to me sounds initially incomprehensible and then absurd.

Comment: I did not say literally. I said literarily.

Comment: @UtkuCanbolat Sorry, the word order you used misled me. I have revised my answer and also the phrasing of your question to make it read more naturally.

Answer (score -2):

Probably not. "Intersect" means to cross over, or divide by passing through. "Meet" or a similar word might be more appropriate. Also, "the blues" makes no sense. The Blue Sea and the Blue Sky would be a  more normal way of describing them: "Where the blue sky meets the blue sea".

Comment: "Intersect" is a legitimate use in a non-mathematical sense.

Comment: You can find several legitimate senses of the ***noun*** (not adjective)  [*blue*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blue#h2) that can take a plural form.

Comment: "The blues" makes sense in this and some other contexts - why do you think it doesn't?